# Mocking aiohttp ClientSession contextmanager using asynctest

Tags: python, python-asyncio, asynctest

I have the following async function:

```py
async def my_func(request):
    # preparation code here
    with aiohttp.ClientSession() as s:
        with s.post(url, headers) as response:
            status_code = response.status
            if status_code == 200:
                json_resp = await response.json()
            elif:
                # more checks
```

Trying to test it but still haven't found a way.

```py
from asynctest.mock import CoroutineMock, MagicMock as AsyncMagicMock

@mock.patch("path_to_function.aiohttp.ClientSession", new_callable=AsyncMagicMock) # this is unittest.mock
def test_async_function(self, mocked_session):
    s = AsyncMagicMock()
    mocked_client_session().__aenter__ = CoroutineMock(side_effect=s)
        session_post = s.post()
        response_mock = AsyncMagicMock()
        session_post.__aenter__ = CoroutineMock(side_effect=response_mock)
        response_mock.status = 200
```

but not working as I want. Any help on how to test context managers would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, Found the solution. I was using `side_effect` instead of `return_value`.Works like a charm. Thank you very much